# How to get d-m-y-h current time and calculator in php

Tags: php

i want get only day, month, year, hour not include minute, second and subtraction it 5 hours. I search but result include minute and second

Ex: now 13/10/2015 18h and i want time now - 5 hours is 13/10/2015 13h

Answer (score 1):

```
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->modify('-5 hours');

echo $dateTime->format('d/m/Y h\h');
```

Read more about [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('d/m/Y G', strtotime('-5 hour')) . 'h';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to strftime() :

```
 <?

 $time=time(); // This is the time in second from the epoch
 $time -= 3600 * 5;  // I subtract 5 hour
 echo strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H", $time); // I print the calculated time
 ?>
```